# How do I set up mysql connections in node.js to throw Out of range errors on arithmatic with unsigned integers?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using node.js and the [Mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) lib which appears to be related to the [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) lib.  I have an unsigned integer field in a mysql database that I am updating by either adding or subtracting as explained below:

**In my tests user with user_id 123456 had 1000 cheese (Unsigned)**

The following sql statment returns no error sets the field to the max value minus 1 (Yikes!)

```
'UPDATE users 
SET user_cheese = user_cheese - 1001 
WHERE user_id = 123456';
```

The following prepared statement and values also results in no error and will set the field to 0

```
'UPDATE users 
SET user_cheese = user_cheese - ? 
WHERE user_id = ?';

preparedVars = [1001, 123456];
```

When I run those statements in php using phpBB's mysqli dbal, I get an Out of range error and the fields are left untouched.  Is there anyway I can replicate said behavior in node.js?

Comment: Given [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html), perhaps your connection needs to be set to strict mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) to be strict - possibly php's client does this at startup:

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

**update:**

just tried simple example and got out of range error - so might be your server configuration:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var c = mysql.createConnection({});
c.query('SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1', console.log);
```

outputs `[Error: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(cast(0 as unsigned) - 1)'] code: 'ER_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE', sqlState: '#22003'`

and this code gives `{ 'CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1': -1 }` as a result:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var c = mysql.createConnection({});
c.query("SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'");
c.query('SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1', console.log);
```